# Apollo client Graphql query variable type error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to execute delete query in which IDis required but I am getting an error. 
"Variable "$id" of required type "ID!" was not provided"

Query

```
export const DELETE_CUSTOMER = gql`
    mutation deleteCustomer($id:ID!){
        deleteCustomer(
            _id: $id
        )
    }
`
```

Mutation code in vuex actions

```
deleteCustomer(vuexContext,id){
        return apollo
        .mutate({
            mutation: DELETE_CUSTOMER,
            variables: id.toString()
        })      
        .then(()=>{
            vuexContext.commit('deleteCustomer',id.toString());
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            throw err;
        });

    }
```

Comment: Can you add the entire Apollo client mutation code and not just the mutation markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `variables` option should be an Object, with each property mapping to an individual variable referenced inside your query. You cannot assign the value of an individual variable to `variables` like you're doing. The corrected method call would look something like:

```
apollo.mutate({
  mutation: DELETE_CUSTOMER,
  variables: { id: id.toString() },
})
```